# reset var to blank after running loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

HELP! I have been banging my head against the wall for hours and hour trying to find a way that once my "game" has ended either by winning or losing my lettersGuessed var resets and no longer displays my userGuesses. I can get through the first loop/ round by setting lettersGuessed = ""; but when a new userGuess  is entered, I get an uncaught type error that lettersGuessed is not a function.

```js
// array  of letters for the computer to chose from 
var letterBank = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]

var lettersGuessed = []

// variables starting value for tally counter
var wins = 0;
var losses = 0;
var guessesLeft = 6;


var compGuess = letterBank[Math.floor(Math.random() * letterBank.length)];


for (var i = 0; i <= guessesLeft; i++) {

  document.onkeyup = function(event) {
    // var for use of collecting key answers for both user and computer. 

    var userGuess = event.key;
    lettersGuessed.push(userGuess);

    // if statements to get a win or loss 
    if (userGuess === compGuess) {
      guessesLeft = 7;
      alert("You won!")
      compGuess = letterBank[Math.floor(Math.random() * letterBank.length)];
      userGuess = "";
      lettersGuessed = "";
      wins++;
    }

    if (userGuess != compGuess) {
      guessesLeft--;
    }
    
    if (guessesLeft === 0) {
      alert("GAME OVER");
      guessesLeft = 6;
      losses++;
      userGuess = "";

      compGuess = letterBank[Math.floor(Math.random() * letterBank.length)];
    }

    // variables to display a win/loss tally and the computer/user guesses    
    var html =
      "<p> your choice: " + userGuess + "</p>" +
      "<p> losses: " + losses + "</p>" +
      "<p> wins: " + wins + "</p>" +
      "<p> Guesses left: " + guessesLeft + "</p>" +
      "<p> Your Guesses so far:" + lettersGuessed + "</p>";

    // sends info collected from html var to the game div
    document.querySelector("#game").innerHTML = html;
  };

};
```

```html
<div id="game">Type a letter</div>
```

Comment: The for loop is confusing and unnecessary. You see the onkeyup to the same function 6 times in a row when assigning it once would do.  This is not the problem you are having but it suggests a different program flow from what is really happening.

Comment: In the past, linters have yelled at me for creating a function inside a loop...

Comment: @MikeWodarczyk thank you! I see what you are suggesting, that because I have already delcared guessesLeft  = a number and guessesLeft-- takes place within my 2nd if statement    I am essentially already running  my game until my guesses left = 0. Which is what I thought I needed to for loop for.  I am BRAND new to JavaScript ( just started last week in class) so I may not be expressing my understanding correctly however that is very helpful and I do understand. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lettersGuessed is an array when declared and not a string. To reset, you need to use the same code as the first initialization. So in your first if statement, replace

```
lettersGuessed = "";
```

with

```
lettersGuessed = [];
```

Comment: Ahmed s.... as soon as I saw this I had a "duh!" moment. Thank you so much. AS I stated in my response to MIke above, I am BRAND new to coding in general but especially JavaScript ( just started learning in my course last week ) and am still working through the logic of it all!